# Camunda external task client polling intervals

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I'm currently developing a Camunda external task client using the Spring Boot external task client. Despite configuring the lock duration, I've noticed that the client is still polling every one minute.

I set my lockDuration using camunda.bpm.client.lockDuration: 5000

My external-client spring boot starter is 7.18

It’s worth nothing tho. that the first four polling is done every 20 seconds but shortly after that it will switch to 1 minute

Comment: Use `lock-duration` instead of `lockDuration`

Comment: it's the same behavior with camunda.bpm.client.lock-duration: 5000

Comment: yaml or properties file? use ….lock-duration=5000 in properties file.

Comment: This was done in my yaml file, same behavior if i ignore the yaml and add lockDuration in my external task handler with annotation @ExternalTaskSubscription(topicName = "myTopic", lockDuration = 5000)

Comment: `lockDuration` doesn't change the polling interval, it only defines how long the tasks are _reserved_ for your client. As far as I know, the polling interval cannot be changed through configuration.

Comment: is there a way, a spring managed component I can override to do that given it's not possible via configuration

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the related documentation here:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/ext-client/#external-task-throughput.
The key words for your question would be **asyncResponseTime** and **backoff strategy**.

asyncResponseTime influence how long a polling interval waits at the server before returning empty.
The backoff strategy (e.g. exponential) controls how the client behaves after the asyncResponseTime was reached and it received an empty result.

You may also find the related Camunda Academy content helpful:
https://academy.camunda.com/c7-platform-java (external worker)

You can also take a look at this example:
https://github.com/rob2universe/c7-external-task-worker/blob/main/src/main/resources/application.yaml